# IE will display this in 2 rows, but I want it displayed in one line

Tags: php, css, layout

I have the following code:

```
<div id="banner">
<a href="http://www.kiubbo.com"><img src="/Logot.png" border=0></a>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxx";
        /* 468x60, creado 13/02/09 */
        google_ad_slot = "7830464607";
        google_ad_width = 468;
        google_ad_height = 60;
        //-->
    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com /pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</div>
```

In Firefox looks fine, but in IE it's displayed in 2 rows (http://www.kiubbo.com)

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #banner a {
      float: left;
   }
   #banner iframe {
      float: left;
   }
   .clear { clear: both; }
</style>
```

And put this after the last script tag inside the banner div:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Plan B, I am trying to get it to work, but I dont know where the code for images goes, before the #banner or inside the brackets {}

Regards,CS

Answer (score 1):

Seems like giving the logo pic

```
'position:absolute;'
```

puts them on the same line in IE. Course they're also on top of each other.